# tracking down include files (include chain)

Tags: c, linux, include, busybox

Sometimes I want to track include files down to the line where a certain type is defined.
For example, after adding a command in busybox, I found the added source is including kernel header file which includes other header files. But different from linux build procedure where the configuration define variables(CONFIG_...) is used to select correct header files(and select correct lines in the header file), in busybox building, those variables are not set so header files are being selected willy-nilly I guess.

So I want to track header files to see for example how the type u32 is typedef-ed and how the correct header files are selected during the build. If I get to know this, I can add some configuration to my busybox build procedure so that the right linux header files and lines would be selected to the final build.

Is there any effective way to find the include file inclusion path? I tried adding -M to the CPPFLAGS while making a .o file to see what files are being included but there was no relevant information outputs.

EDIT : I used grep to find the files typedef-ing the type then and altered the typename of each candidate file to find the finally used header file. Then used grep to find files including that file. and altered the include filename to know out the real including file(real including file makes error during inclusion, because of the altered file name.). I repeated this and this way I could track the include path. Maybe this is the only method?

Answer (score 0):

To look at the typedef name's actual type, you need to look at the preprocessor's output:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

The option for it on gcc is -E. This output will also have recursively included content from your header files.

Comment: Thanks Arun, About the gcc -E option I tried like  make CFLAGS="-E" ARCH=sparc CROSS_COMPILE=sparc-abc-elf- drivers/usb/host/abc-hcd.o but couldn't see the type on stdout yet. I'll try.